# Rubik's cube's face into date

Tags: mathematics, rubiks-cube

Solve this Rubik's cube's face into date

[image]

For puzzle masters who can not see pictures / color blind

```
B B W
Y G B  = 21/05/2013
G Y B 

R O G
B G B  = 16/09/1980
G W W

O R R
W G G  =  ?
R Y G
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A Rubik's cube has six faces, so there are six different colors to work with.

This suggests to me that it's

> a base-6 encoding, where each color corresponds to a number from 0-5.
> Sanity check: in base 6, a 2-digit number can represent up to 35 in base 10, so 2 digits will be enough for the month and day in base 6.  That leaves 5 digits for the year, which can represent up to 7775 base 10.  So it's an appropriate number of digits.

So I changed each of the dates into

> Base 6 representation.
> 21/05/2013 becomes 33/05/13153
> 16/09/1980 becomes 24/13/13100
> Then I looked at the pattern of the color blocks.
> These patterns fit:
> 330513153 matches the pattern BBWYGBGYB from the first block;
> 241313100 matches the pattern ROGBGBGWW from the 2nd block.

Thus the colors represent:

> Digits:
>  White = 0, Green = 1, Red = 2, Blue = 3, Orange = 4, Yellow = 5.

Read the pattern from the 3rd block:

> ORRWGGRYG = 422011251
>  Day (base 6) = 42
>  Month (base 6) = 20
>  Year (base 6) = 11251
>  42/20/11251 converted to base 10 is 26/12/1615

So my answer is:

> December 26, 1615

I'm not sure the significance of this day, if there is one.